# Why doesn't strpbrk() find a character?

Tags: c++, string

```
char operators[] = "+-*/^(";  
char* input = new char[100];  
char* output = new char[100];  
char* operadores = new char[100];  
char* pch = input;  
char* pch2 = input;  
cout << "Expresion: " <<endl; cin.getline(input,100);  
cout << input <<endl;  
pch2 = strpbrk (pch2, operators);  
pch = strtok (pch, "+-*/^(");  
while (pch != NULL){  
    strcat (output, pch);  
    pch = strtok (NULL, "+-*/^(");  
    strcat (operadores, pch2);  
}  

cout << "Salida: " << output <<endl;
cout << "Operadores: " << operadores <<endl;
cout << "Entrada: " << input <<endl;
cout << "pch2 = " << pch2 <<endl;
```

My problem is that the function `strpbrk()` doesn't work.  It doesn't return NULL; I've proved it. But I need a `char` to put in a stack, and `cout` doesn't show me what character is pointed by `pch2`.

Comment: Since you've proved that `strpbrk` doesn't work, I suggest you file a bug report with your compiler vendor. That's a very serious fault that you have discovered.

Comment: Oh, I doubt it's the compiler's fault. Clearly, C/C++ are broken languages and nobody should ever use either. ;p

Comment: More seriously, `strpbrk` is obviously not the problem here. The problem is in how you are calling it. Are you prepared to entertain a solution that involves fixing your use of `strpbrk`? I also wonder why you are using C strings instead of std::string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing yourself - the program is designed to confuse.

You have both `pch` and `pch2` pointing at the same input string - `input`.  You call `strpbrk()` to find one of the operators, saving that position in `pch2`.  You then call `strtok()` on `pch`, and it finds the character that `strpbrk()` just found, and writes a NUL `'\0'` over it.  So, it appears that `pch2` points to the NUL at the end of a string.  In the body of the loop, you then concatenate the empty string that `pch2` points to onto your target list of operators.

Personally, I avoid using `strtok()` precisely because it mangles the input string.  If you are going to use it, you are likely to need to work on a duplicate of the string, because `strtok()` writes NUL bytes over it.

Your diagnostic output at the end should show that the first section of the input - up to the first operator - only.

Beware of casting aspersions at standard library functions or compilers 'not working'.  It is the mark of a tyro; 99.9999% of the time, it is a user error and not a system error.  On those very, very, very rare occasions when you're correct (ooh, look - I've just won my third multi-million lottery prize; that's more likely, even though I don't buy lottery tickets), the way that you describe the problem is different.  You describe the issue as one of utter astonishment; you document the working test cases; then you explain how the edge case you've found should work and the result - and you still aren't sure whether it is a bug in your code or in the system.

---

As others diagnosed, you do not initialize `operadores` to an empty string, so concatenating to it leads to undefined behaviour.

There's really no need to allocate the 100-byte strings:

```
char input[100];  // Cleaner, simpler, more reliable
```